# How can I have a form where the text in the input disappears when clicked? (for feedburner form)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, feedburner

I've got the following "subscribe by e-mail" form:

```
<form style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px;text-align:center;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=food101coil', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
<p>enter e-mail:</p>
<p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="email"/></p><input type="hidden" value="food101coil" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><input type="submit" value="SEND" /></form>
```

I want to move the "enter e-mail" section inside the form part.  So that when the user clicks on it, the text will disappear.

Could someone please help me with how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="email" onclick="this.value='';" value="enter e-mail" />
```

Not tested, should work though!

Comment: this will clear your email field by every click modify it to this
<input type="text" name="email" onclick="if(this.value=='enter e-mail'){this.value='';}" value="enter e-mail" />

Answer (score 3):

The following code will do what you want, but also maintain an email once entered..

**HTML**

```
<input id="email" type="text" style="width:140px" name="email" value="enter e-mail"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var emailfield = document.getElementById('email');
 emailfield.onfocus = function(){
  if (this.value == 'enter e-mail') this.value = '';
 }
 emailfield.onblur= function(){
  if (this.value == '') this.value = 'enter e-mail';
 }
</script>
```

Live example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YS2Xm/

Comment: This almost work.  The form is empty when the page is loaded.  If I click on it once and then click away - it creates the text...

Comment: @Tal, forgot to add the value attribute in the HTML .. answer updated.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.

The solution from Grumpy actually did the trick.

Comment: @Tal, not sure what does not work ... did you check the example ? Keep in mind that the solution from ApoY2k and Grumpy does not take into consideration a user that uses the tab key to select the email input box..

Comment: Hi Gaby,
 thanks for the efforts.  I am not sure why it doesn't work, I tried it in various ways.  It could be for the way WordPress behaves (I am using the code inside the text widget). I voted you up any way :)  cheers, Tal